# Schwa syncope in "hundred"

Tags: phonology, phonetics, pronunciation

My girlfriend noticed that I say when I pronounce a word like 'hundred' it sounds like I'm deleting the schwa sound in the final syllable and pronouncing the word mroe like, "hundrd". Does this fall under schwa syncope?

Comment: There's a cardinal vowel which is a feature of the language and *articulation accuracy* which is a feature of an individual person.

Comment: You could call it that.  I think I've heard that change also in the pronunciation of "hybrid".